# java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, xml, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager

I try to use viewPager with the tablayout but when i set adapter with the view pager i'm getting error "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass() on a null object reference" i don't understand why this error is show.

view pager set Adapter:

```
viewPager= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager_id);
  viewPager.setAdapter(newViewPagerAdapterUseThisClass(getSupportFragmentManager(),14));
```

Adapter clss:

```
class ViewPagerAdapterUseThisClass extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    int countTabItem;
     ViewPagerAdapterUseThisClass(FragmentManager fm,int contTabItem) {
        super(fm);

        this.countTabItem=contTabItem;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        if(position==0){
            EnthusamTab enthusamTab=new EnthusamTab();
            return enthusamTab;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return countTabItem;
    }
}
```

view pager xml file:

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout_id"
            android:id="@+id/viewPager_id"/>
```

Error log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:380)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.add(BackStackRecord.java:375)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:103)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1034)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1248)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1642)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19861)
                                                                                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
                                                                                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19861)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1081)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19861)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19861)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19861)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19861)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19861)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:689)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19861)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2275)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1366)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1619)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6343)
                                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
                                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
                                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
                                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6126)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: You're telling the Adapter that it's got 14 items, but you're returning null for all of them except position 0.

Comment: sorry it's my fault thanks @MikeM.

Comment: Does the problem solved here ?

Answer (score 50):

This exception occurs when you return `null` at `getItem(int position)` method of `PagerAdapter`.

You have to set a return value(n) at `getCount()` method and return a `Fragment` at `getItem(int position)` method for all (0 .. n-1) positions.

For instance, if you return 3 from `getCount()` method, then you must return a not-null `Fragment` for positions 0, 1 and 2 at `getItem(int position)` method. If you return a null for position 0, 1 or 2, you'll get:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object
>   reference

```
private static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    ...

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new XFragment();
            case 1:
                return new YFragment();
            case 2:
                return new ZFragment();
            default:
                return null; // Problem occurs at this condition!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: May be it's late but I want to ask how you know that is that exact reason? I just curious to know how you get the exact reason. The log is not so helpful.

Comment: @Ankur_009 FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem (it is at shared log) calls getItem method. If getItem returns null NPE occurs.

Comment: I think from my understanding, first you have check onMeasue() -> populate() -> addNewItem() -> instantiateItem() will call getItem(). That was your thoughtprocess?

Comment: I was having a null initialization for Fragment. Now solved

Answer (score 11):

This error usually comes when you have few fragments to return than the count specified. Like for example, returning count=3, and you return null on the second position. 
Please note that count is a zero based index.

Answer (score 3):

Return for all counts. Try this:

```
Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            EnthusamTab enthusamTab=new EnthusamTab();
            return enthusamTab;

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Problem is occurring to return null in Fragment count function

```
 @Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new XFragment();
        case 1:
            return new YFragment();
        case 2:
            return new ZFragment();
        default:
            return null; // Problem occurs at this condition!
    }
}
```

Here outer bracket occurs error.

So the above-mentioned Answer is right and it's working.

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {

        Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
        return tab1;
    }
    if (position == 2) {
        Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
        return tab2;
    } else {
        Tab3 tab3 = new Tab3();
        return tab3;
    }

}
```

it right answers.

Answer (score 2):

According to what i see you are returning null in this method:

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        if(position==0){
            EnthusamTab enthusamTab=new EnthusamTab();
            return enthusamTab;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to do this in `getCount` do count of all fragments you have: like 1..5

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 5; //her 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This type of exception only occurs when you try to use method `getCount()` to return value more than you intialize in tabs.
Change your return value.

Answer (score 2):

**Just use the code given below. It avoids null error and runs smoothly**

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

      return new Tab1( );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I forget to set break command. Check your break operators at first.

Now I have this code:

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new FollowersFragment();
            case 1:
                return new PostsFragment();
            case 2:
                return new ReactsFragment();
            case 3:
                return new StoriesFragment();
            case 4:
                return new FollowersFragment();
            case 5:
                return new FollowersFragment();
            case 6:
                return new FollowersFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {

            Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
            return tab1;
        }
        if (position == 2) {
            Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
            return tab2;
        } else {
            Tab3 tab3 = new Tab3();
            return tab3;
        }

    }
```

Comment: How does this relate to the original question? Please provide more context

Comment: i just had the same problem and that code worked for me